# Usage of: 'since', 'for' and 'in'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, usage, present-perfect

Which of these is grammatically correct?

> **1.** a) He has been working under my direct supervision since the last two years
>
> **1.** b) He has been working under my direct supervision for the last two years
>
> **2.** a) He has not met her since a very long time
>
> **2.** b) He has not met her in a very long time

Which of the above are correct?
Are all of them correct? My friend says 1.b and 2.b are correct, but I am not sure. Or is this an American English and British English thing? (He mostly goes by American English)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1b) and 2b) are correct.

You could correct 1a) as:

> He has been working under my direct supervision **since two years ago**.

and 2a):

> He has not met her **since long ago**.

*Since* as used here points to a specific time, not a time span as in your examples.
See the definition [since](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/since) senses 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want common usage following proper grammar:

`Since` is *usually/most commonly/should be* used as a **conjunction**, in this meaning, should be followed with a clause (sentence). There are exceptions such as `since yesterday` `since today` which are common phrases almost accepted as proper English.

> He has been working under my direct supervision since *he first started*

`for/in` is a **preposition**, in this meaning, and is only followed by a noun, to complete a prepositional phrase, like in 1.a) and 2.b)

The usage precise difference between the `prepositions` for and in, is difficult to pinpoint, you could say usage depends on US/British/Australian English, and certain phrases may tend to use one over the other.

Therefore if you take a grammar test, of correct English, and there is only one correct answer, 1b and 2b are correct. Local English, slang English, poor english, instagram english may accept 1a 2a.