# "Since" in English language

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammar, american-english, spoken-english

I understand that ‘**since**’ is used to refer a point in the past till now. However I have a doubt on the below example. Please tell me which one is the correct?

> 1. I have been working here **since** 2 years.
> 2. I have been working here **since** 2 years ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 'since', 'for' and 'in'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37226/difference-between-since-for-and-in)

Comment: Regardless of the answer on that earlier question, my personal advice would be to always favour ***for*** over ***since*** in such contexts (in which case you would never want to include ***ago***).

Comment: **two years** by itself does not establish a point-in-time. Two years is a duration.    **Two years ago** on the other hand refers to a point-in-time two years back in the past.   *She received her degree two years ago.*

Answer (score 1):

Only your second example is correct. You can't use "**since**" with time durations. You can use it only with points in time.

"*2 years*" is a duration, while "*2 years ago*" is a point in the past (like **yesterday**, **last year** or **birth**)

- I have worked here since yesterday/last year/birth/2 years ago.

As the comments advise, it is better to use "**for**" in such context with time durations.

- I have worked here for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Neither example is a preferred way of using "since."  Here are alternative versions with brief explanations as to how they use references to time.

> I have worked here for two years.

This first example uses the speaker's current moment in time as the point of reference to express how long he or she have been doing something.  That the speaker may have been doing something else before two years ago is irrelevant with this statement.

> I started working here two years ago.

This second example uses a past moment in time as the point of reference to express how long the speaker has been doing something.  Again, that the speaker may have been doing something else before two years ago is irrelevant with this statement.

> It has been two years since I started working.

This third example uses a past moment in time as the point of reference to express how long it has been since something changed.  This is the important distinction: what the speaker was doing before two years ago was important.  The `change in condition` is more important than what has happened since.

> I haven't been unemployed since two years ago.

This fourth example uses a past moment in time as the point of reference to express how long it has been since something changed.  However, this time what the speaker was doing before the moment of change is more important than what the speaker was doing after the moment of change.

We see this perspective of the `change in condition` in the official definition.  From the Merriam-Webster Dictionary:

> **[Since](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/since)** [1]:from a definite past time until now (has stayed there ever since), [2]:before the present time (long since dead), [3]:after a time in the past (has since become rich).

Comment: An estimated 40,000 hits in Google Books for [since a year ago](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22since+a+year+ago%22) suggests you're wrong to label OP's second example "incorrect". I might personally *prefer* to use ***for two years***, but that doesn't mean ***since*** isn't syntactically valid (it's just a slight shift of emphasis from ***length** of timespan* to ***start** of timespan*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Possibly, but the frequency response of a fragment isn't authoritative.  [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=since+a+year+ago&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csince%20a%20year%20ago%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsince%20a%20year%20ago%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSince%20a%20year%20ago%3B%2Cc0) suggests peak popularity of the phrase "since a year ago" between 1910-1950 with a rapid decline since.

Comment: @JBH - Google Ngrams isn't authoritative, either. Besides, "in decline" is not the same as "incorrect". As for that bit about the phrase being in a "rapid decline", it's still being used aplenty in [current news stories](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22since+a+year+ago%22&safe=active&tbm=nws&start=10&sa=N&biw=1745&bih=945&dpr=1.1).

Comment: I absolutely agree that idiomatically, *since [timespan] ago* is a "declining" usage (though if we're to believe NGrams, my preferred alternative [*For two years I have...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=For+two+years+I+have&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFor%20two%20years%20I%20have%3B%2Cc0) has *also* declined significantly over the past century). I just don't think you should bluntly categorise the usage as "incorrect".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, oh, if that's the issue I'll modify the intro.  No problem.

Comment: Sorry if my first comment came across as hostile nit-picking, I do actually think that ELL learners should focus on *current* idiomatically standard usages until they reach a very high level of fluency (at which point they might find ELU more suitable anyway). But there's a fine line between *Don't bother with that usage because it's uncommon / outdated / etc.* and *...because it isn't / never was valid English*. Anyway, following your edit I'm more than happy to reverse my (admittedly, somewhat severe) downvote. The system worked, in that the answer is "improved", imho.