# Tense after since

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct?

A. It’s been forty years since I’ve been living here.

B. It’s forty years since I’ve been living here.

C. It’s been forty years since I lived here.

What tense should be before the word 'since' and after it?

> Subject+ has been + time+ since+ subject + past.

Is this right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Since" in English language](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147264/since-in-english-language)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you want "since" at all? Only option C is correct, but it means that you lived here at one point in the past - but you moved away forty years ago.

If you mean that you *started* living here forty years ago and you still do, then you just want

> It's been forty years that I've been living here.

or more idiomatically

> I've been living here for forty years.